# Convert variable contents to string in python

Tags: python, string, casting, type-conversion

I have a variable which has an equation .I'm trying convert the equation that the varibale has into a string and compute the results

Eg

```
def func1(x):
  y = x + 5
  return y, 'x+5'
```

x as input can vary since I'm iterating
through multiple values

Say

```
h[0][1] = 5
func1(h[0][1])
```

Output - 10, "h[0][1]+5"

Required result
I need x+5 as string and the computed result of y as a while calling func1

Eval and exec seemed like a probable solution but they perform the inverse of what is needed

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: linear algebra and programming logic are not really compatible out of the box

Comment: @Selcuk I need the output of an equation and the eqaution solved to get that output to log

Comment: "I need the output of an equation and the eqaution solved to get that output to log" what does that mean?

Comment: From the provided example, I need the value of Y , 15 in one column and X+5, the equation used to get the value in the next column

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand why you'd want this but given that the variable holding the equation would be known when coding, you could just wrap the equation in a function. Eg:

```
def add_five(x):
    return (x + 5, "x + 5")

x = 10
y = add_five(x)
print("Answer is", y[0])
print("Equation is", y[1])
```

Comment: Im running multiple iterations and each time the equation changes based on the constraints. I need to track the value as well the equation in a specific iteration. Need something that dynamically does this

Comment: How does the equation change with the iteration? You can't change an equation on the run, you can only change value of variable you are using or select from a selection of equations using a select statement. Can you provide some code to show what you are trying to do?